# Message queue function msgsnd with less arguments

Tags: perl, message-queue

The 'msgsnd' function actual declaration is below

```
int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
```

But, there is a perl program which used in the following manner

```
msgsnd($qid, pack("l! l! a*", $type, $type, $cmd), 1)
```

This has only 3 arguments. How does this works?

Comment: When a Perl binding or implementation is written for libraries in other languages changes are often made to the interface.  Often things need not be passed, or may be passed behind scenes if Perl's implementation is object oriented.  However, this question doesn't provide even the basic description of the problem.  It is way too broad, and not focused on a problem with code but rather on operation of a software library.

Comment: [This](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/doio.c#l2350) is how it works.

Comment: `int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);` doesn't look like Perl...

Answer (score 1):

The [usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/msgsnd.html) is actually

```
msgsnd ID,MSG,FLAGS
```

Perl strings aren't NUL-terminated like in C; string scalars (such as `MSG`) contain a field with the length of the data in the string buffer in addition to the string buffer itself, so all the necessary information is available in those three parameters to make the underlying `msgsnd()` call.

[Here](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/443bd156a6baaf7a8fe6b6b05fcf6c4178140ed2:/doio.c#l2356) is the implementation of Perl's `msgsnd` operator.